# how to avoid "SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode" message with jqGrid filterloader

Tags: jqgrid

In jqGrid filter toolbar, When i search a numeric value on a numeric valued column with leading zero such as 01, 02, 00 etc, then

> SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode

message is coming. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem exist because jqGrid generate the code like `parseFloat(01)` (for `formatter: "float"` and `formatter: "number"`) or `parseInt(01, 10)` (for `formatter: "integer"`) if one enter `01` in the searching field.

I fixed the bug (see [the commit](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/f42b169ebbade6ac93668510df427be718f772d6)) in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). You can try the latest code directly from GitHub if you would use URLs described in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs#access-githib-code-from-rawgit):

```html
<link href="//rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/i18n/grid.locale-de.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>
```

(one should add `http:` or `https:` prefix if one uses the URLs from local files)

Comment: Thank you Oleg. In my own solution i had used val = " ' " + val + " ' ".

Comment: @Naveenk: You are welcome! Thank you too for reporting of the problem.